# Robotframework Create LOOP TO FIND Element

Tags: python, robotframework

```
${i}=    Set Variable    0
FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    0    20
\    Test Scroll
\    Element Text Should Be    xpath=//android.view.View[@index='0']//android.view.View[@text='Wiki']
\    ${Additional_pack_th}=    Get Text    xpath=//android.view.View[@text='Wiki']
\    ${status}    Run Keyword And Return Status    BuiltIn.Should Be Equal As Strings    ${Additional_pack_th}    Wiki
\    BuiltIn.Exit For Loop If    ${status} == TRUE
\    BuiltIn.Continue For Loop If    ${status} == False
${i}=    BuiltIn.Evaluate    ${i}+1
```

Is this the correct way? My execution fails here... Please help!

Comment: Could you please share your Error Message? Also you dont need to iterate ${i} Robotframework does it for your with the loop itself

Comment: What does _"fails here"_ mean? How does it fail, and where is "here"?

Answer (score 0):

One problem is the syntax. You do not need the `\` on each line, and you need to add an `END` statement. Also, you don't need to initialize or increment `${i}`, robot does that automatically when you use a FOR loop.

```
FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    0    20
    Test Scroll
    Element Text Should Be    xpath=//android.view.View[@index='0']//android.view.View[@text='Wiki']
    ${Additional_pack_th}=    Get Text    xpath=//android.view.View[@text='Wiki']
    ${status}    Run Keyword And Return Status    BuiltIn.Should Be Equal As Strings    ${Additional_pack_th}    Wiki
    BuiltIn.Exit For Loop If    ${status} == TRUE
    BuiltIn.Continue For Loop If    ${status} == False
END
```

Also, this isn't correct:

```
${status} == TRUE
```

After `${status}` is replaced with it's value, the result must be a proper python expression. The bare word `TRUE` isn't known to python. The status will only ever be "PASS" or "FAIL", so you need to check for one of those values. And finally, you don't need to prefix built-in keywords with `BuiltIn.`.

The statement thus should look like this:

```
Exit For Loop If    '${status}' == 'TRUE'
```

You don't need the call to `Continue For loop if` since continutation is the default thing it will do. You only need to use "continue" if you want to skip over some keywords and start the next iteration. You aren't skipping any keywords so it is impletely unnecessary.

The final version should look like this:

```
FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    0    20
    Test Scroll
    Element Text Should Be    xpath=//android.view.View[@index='0']//android.view.View[@text='Wiki']
    ${Additional_pack_th}=    Get Text    xpath=//android.view.View[@text='Wiki']
    ${status}    Run Keyword And Return Status    BuiltIn.Should Be Equal As Strings    ${Additional_pack_th}    Wiki
    Exit For Loop If    '${status}' == 'TRUE'
END
```

**However**, all of that being said, I'm not sure this will work. It depends on what `Test Scroll` does. Since you never change the xpath statement on each iteration, it will likely find the same element over and over.

I don't know what your application looks like, but maybe you need to use `${i}` in your xpath:

```
Element Text Should Be    xpath=//android.view.View[@index='${i}']//android.view.View[@text='Wiki']
```